# Global accelerator in java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, shortcut, accelerator

I have made accelerators in my java gui by using setAccelerator(), and they work unless something with the same key binding is in focus. Is there a way to enable them globally so the action is triggered no matter what if the window has focus?

```
jmi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, Event.CTRL_MASK))
```

Comment: You have two or more windows of your single java-program that have the same key binding. And you want that binding to be applied globally to only one of those windows. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Global Event Dispatching](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/06/global-event-dispatching/). You should be able to use a KeyEventDispatcher to intercept any key event to do your custom processing.